# Factory method - when objects need information to get initalized

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented

Lets look on a simple example: assume that I have three classes implemeting `IPersonRepository`: `SQLPersonRepository`, `WebPersonRepository`, `InMemoryPersonRepository`. I also have `PersonRepositoryFactory` class which is simple Factory method pattern implementation - contains `GetPersonRepository` methods which have enum/string as parameter. How could I create Factory pattern (or in other words centralize my object creation) when `SQLPersonRepository` needs dependency for: `SQLConnection` or string to database path, `WebPersonRepository` needs some http settings object and `InMemoryPersonRepository` has no dependencies? I could pass it in Factory constructor or as method parameter but it'd be ugly, unclean and unmaintable especially if I had more `IPersonRepository` implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to implement `PersonRepositoryFactory` as an abstract factory, with subclasses `SQLPersonRepositoryFactory`, `WebPersonRepositoryFactory` and `InMemoryPersonRepositoryFactory`. Those subclasses can have different constructor parameters (like `SQLConnection`, `HttpSetting` or no parameters). Once you have initialized those three factory objects, you can use them through an ordinary factory method for producing of many `IPersonRepository` objects, all with the same SQL connection or http settings.